# Suppress "Chrome didn't shutdown correctly" message in Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, command-line

Ist it possible to supress the Message "Chrome didn't shutdown correctly" completely in Chromium? 
The best would be via commandline. ("--disable-infobars" did not help)

Answer (score 4):

Pass **--disable-session-crashed-bubble** commandline option to Chrome

Comment: It looks like the answer, but please add some text to it.

Comment: Not working anymore, check this https://superuser.com/questions/237608/how-to-hide-chrome-warning-after-crash

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be useful to you, but if you launch the browser via command line in app mode like so

```
--app=http://yourdomain.com
```

The message bubble is automatically disabled.